# Pdf Viewer implementation causes Gradle project sync is failed

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, pdf-viewer

I created a project on Android Studio 2.3.3 and added pdf viewer as below:

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

I can build the project without error and I can display pdf file.

Now I am trying to add this library to a new project that I created on Android studio 3.0.1 as below, Gradle project sync is failed.

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

I am getting this errors;

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3.

My gradle.build;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.com.pdfviewer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve `com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3`

**ANS :** You should use **latest version** of dependencies

Use this

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4'
```

**OR** if you want to use more stable version:

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

Instead of this

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

for more information check docs of  [**`com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer`**](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Comment: I created a new project and just add `compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'` it gave me same errors. Could it be related to my gradle? `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`

Comment: @james for test case try this `buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"`

Comment: `Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.`

Comment: I changed it 26.0.2 after this warning but it is failed again

Answer (score 0):

Well i setup exact things which you mentioned at my end in Android Studio version 3.0.1 with implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3' and is working fine without any issues.

Else do one thing Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and then try to open same project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting then Gradle then unclick offline Work box. it works fine in my android studio 3.0

Answer (score -1):

how fix Error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2.